# Upload FTP File With Argv

Tags: python, upload, ftp

I'm getting a message that "name 'ftp' is not defined"
Seems like I might have messed something else up too.

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from sys import argv
import os

filename = argv

ftp = FTP(ftp.server.com)
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.storbinary('STOR %s', open('%s', 'rb')) (filename, filename)
```

Comment: `ftp = FTP('ftp.server.com')` (note: quotes around domain name)

Answer (score 1):

sys.argv is a list.  The first item in the list is the command, the next items are the arguments given.  You probably want filename = argv[1].

You will need to give values to username, password for this to work as well.

Comment: FTP vs ftp is being used mostly properly. Note that the name "ftp" is being bound as the instance of the constructed FTP object. The failure is actually happening because the server name string wasn't quoted.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand argv! I'm getting 
`File "ftp.py", line 9, in ?
    ftp.login("username", "password")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 362, in login
    if resp[0] == '3': resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 241, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 216, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login incorrect.[`
I can't discern whether this is someone I'm doing wrong with the script...

Comment: You need to have actual values for username and password.  ftp.login('wpm', 'flail_48') will only work if wpm is a bonafide ftp user for the server, and if wpm's password is actually 'flail_48'.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of ftp.server.com is illegal- you need to quote it. Python believes that "ftp" is, at that point, an identifier, which you are trying to pull the field "server" from, and finally the field "com". Since you want it to be a sever name string instead, quote it.

Additionally, you are using `sys.argv` incorrectly. Argv is a list of string, not a single string. Your filename should be `" ".join(argv[1:])` instead, to capture the command line approximately verbatim. (argv[0] is the script itself.)